# How to keep x/y coordinates while creating a raster from a data frame in r with terra package?

Tags: r, spatial-query

[Resulted raster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qt20.png)

I have a dataframe with x and y coordinates, containing predicted values.
I created an empty raster with the right ext, res and crs and I want to assign the predicted values. I used the function setValues from the terra package, however the function does not consider the x and y from the dataframe and read the data in another manner.
It results with a raster that contains only the horizontal (x) info --> look at the picture.
Is there an alternative function in the terra package where it is possible to add the x/y coordinates?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably `rast(x, type="xyz")`, but it is hard to say since there is no example. Also, you can probably avoid this whole situation by using `terra::predict`.